# ActionScript 3.0 Передача Cookies от клиента к серверу через Flash

Tags: actionscript-3

Собрал Flash загрузчик на ActionScript 3.0. Использовал URLRequest + FileReference. При тестировании в браузере Mozila, php-скрипт почему-то не видит Cookies данные клиента. Передача файла на этом обрывается. На стороне сервера обязательна авторизация пользователя, в противном случае exit;

Пока вижу одно единственное решение. Передавать Cookies данные сначала во Flash, с помощью FlashVars, а затем отправлять их оттуда на сервер. Но есть ли объяснение, почему Mozila отказывается передавать Cookies? А может быть есть и решение этой проблемы? Во всех остальных браузерах всё работает стабильно.